# Swift range: not including first element

Tags: swift, string, range

For getting the elements in a certain range up to but excluding `index`, the following command is used:

```
let substr=mystr[..<index]
```

But how can I get a certain range, beginning from the first element *after* `index`? It should be like:

```
let substr=mystr[index<..] //does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `index(after:)` method to get the following index:

```
let mystr = "Hello"
let index = mystr.startIndex
if index < mystr.endIndex {
    let substr = mystr[mystr.index(after: index)...]
    print(substr)   // "ello\n"
}
```

Comment: There is no shortcut?

Comment: No there is no shortcut. Btw You would need to check if the index is less than endIndex to avoid crashing your app